# Nesting abstract beans in Spring and init-method does not seem to work

Tags: java, spring

I have the following construct Spring XML (Spring 3.1):

```
<bean id="taskRunner" abstract="true" init-method="startThreads"
      class="my.class.TaskRunner" />
...
<bean id="taskRunnerA" parent="taskRunner">
  <constructor-arg name="foo">...</constructor-arg>
  <property name="bar">...</property>
</bean>
```

And I am trying to separate out the init method into a higher level abstract bean:

```
<bean id="taskRunnerLauncher" abstract="true" init-method="startThreads" />

<bean id="taskRunner" abstract="true" depends-on="taskRunnerLauncher"
      class="my.class.TaskRunner" />
...
<bean id="taskRunnerA" parent="taskRunner">
  <constructor-arg name="foo">...</constructor-arg>
  <property name="bar">...</property>
</bean>
```

Somehow this does not work, i.e. startThreads() is never invoked in the second case. Does anybody know why? Does Spring support nested abstract beans?

My idea for doing this is so I can override "taskRunnerLauncher" in unit tests and set it to "mock" or "java.lang.Object" and suppress startThreads() call (which starts new thread and making it a pain to test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody know why?

The `taskRunnerLauncher` bean is set to be `abstract`. This means it will only act as a template for other beans. Spring will not actually create a bean for it. Therefore there won't be any invocation of `startThreads` because there is nothing to invoke it on.

Comment: but this is my intent - taskRunnerA is the concrete bean, taskRunner and taskRunnerLauncher are abstract ones...

Comment: @alexandroid Instead of `depends-on`, try using `parent`. I'll admit I haven't really played with `abstract` bean declarations.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I mistakenly used `depends-on` instead of `parent` attribute on `taskRunner` bean.